# Is "of" or "off" correct?

Tags: word-usage, british-english

> Films representing the Duke saying good-bye to his favourite canary on
>   the eve of the trial were in readiness weeks before the event was due
>   to take place; other films depicted the Duchess holding imaginary
>   consultations with fictitious lawyers or making a light repast **off**
>   specially advertised vegetarian sandwiches during a supposed luncheon
>   interval. As far as human foresight and human enterprise could go
>   nothing was lacking to make the trial a success.

from [East of the Web](http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/UnkiBlow802.shtml)

Is *off* meant to be *of*"?

Answer (score 2):

In British English, we can use 'off' to talk about what we eat - I dined off turkey and ham yesterday, or what enables us to live - some people live off vegetables only; my cousin lives off her savings. To dine is to eat a meal (a 'repast'). Saki is using 'off' in that way. The usage is a little old-fashioned and formal ('Saki' was writing more than 100 years ago). The usage mainly survives in phrasal verbs such as 'live/dine off' (or 'live/dine on').

> dine on/off something
>   phrasal verb
>   formal
>   to eat a particular kind of
>   food for dinner, especially expensive food
>   We dined on lobster and
>   strawberries.

[Dine on/off (Longmans Dictionary)](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/dine-on-off)
[Live off (Longmans Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/live-off)